# Trouble using fread() to convert a binary file to a struct

Tags: c, struct, binaryfiles, fread

I'm having trouble using fread() to convert a binary file into a linked list of structs.

The struct:

```
struct MdbRec {
    char name[16];
    char  msg[24];
};
```

Relevant code:

```
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen( argv[1], "rb" );

    struct List db;
    initList(&db);
    struct MdbRec *data = (struct MdbRec *)malloc(sizeof(struct MdbRec));
    struct Node *last;
    while( fread( data, 40, 1, file ) )
    {
            struct MdbRec *message = (struct MdbRec *)malloc(sizeof(struct MdbRec));
            message = data;
            if( !db.head )
            {
                    last = addFront( &db, message );
                    db.head = last;
            }
            else
                    last = addAfter( &db, last, message );
            if( fseek( file, 40, SEEK_CUR ) != 0)
                    break;
            printf("read\n");
    }
    free(data);
    removeAllNodes( &db );
```

addFront() and addAfter are methods of the linkedlist structure that mallocs space the data field.

When I run it with Valgrind it shows that I'm successfully having 2 allocations of memory. One is obviously the data variable. The other 568 bytes and it's very confusing to me. Valgrind says the error is coming from when I run fread().

Comment: ` message = data;` will overwrite the value you assigned to message via the initialiser.

Comment: jae would be disappointed

Comment: @Soke, he's just as disappointed in you if you're finding this question ;)

Comment: I found this googling "MdbRec" because I was confused what "Rec" stood for :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a memory leak:

```
struct MdbRec *message = (struct MdbRec *)malloc(sizeof(struct MdbRec));
message = data;
```

as `message` is now pointing to `data` and no longer points to the just `malloc()`d memory, which is now unreachable. I suspect you actually meant to *copy* `data` to `message`:

```
*message = *data;
```

Other points:

- Check result of `fopen()` before using it.
- There appears to be no reason to not use a stack allocated object for `data`, which would avoid needless dynamic allocation management for it.
- The `fread()` argument that specifies the size of the object to read, `40`, is error prone. Any changes to `struct MdbRec` would break it: use `sizeof(struct MdbRec)` instead.
- Casting the return value of `malloc()` is not necessary and possibly dangerous (see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked.

I added the fopen() check, though the issue wasn't there.
The other errors were things that initially had right but changed in attempts to debug this.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct MdbRec *message = (struct MdbRec *)malloc(sizeof(struct MdbRec));
message = data;
```

You reallocated a `struct MdbRec` and discarded it.

Comment: As hmjd pointed out, I meant to copy data to message. I didn't intend to discard it. My mistake, thanks for the help.